# Deleting files from Temp directory on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an iOS application where im downloading files from server and storing it on a sql database and later when user click on a message it will unzip files and display content of the file.

For this purpose I wrote this function which I thought is right for what I want to do:

This is to get file from sql and unzip those files on temp folder

```
NSString *unzipFolder = [[CommonFunctions getCachePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"];
```

and once user done with viewing this message i'm trying to delete this temp folder so when user click on a next message to display  it has space on temp folder, since function can always unzip files later-on to display

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:unzipFolder error:&error];
```

My issue is When i run function to delete unzip folders content it doesn't delete this content and when user click on next item from message it display previous message images (Since they not cleaning up and auto replacing).

How can i solve this issue, and how can i store files on iOS with Temp folder and clean p when user done with it.

Answer (score 3):

Check if file exists:

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:unzipFolder])
{
  NSError *error;
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:unzipFolder error:&error];
  NSLog@"Error : %@",[error description]);
}
else
{
  NSLog@"File Exists Not Exists");
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU I implemented if statement but still it doesn't work, part of messages still repeating, How can i make sure that above function get called as soon as user change or navigate to another view which is list of messages? :)

Comment: use delegate to make call back function