# Open file using temporary storage

Tags: ios, swift, file, download

I have some code to download and open a file:

```
//Get documents directory URL
let documentsDirectoryUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first

let sourceUrl = NSURL(string:"https://download.com/file.pdf")!

//Get the file name and create a destination URL
let fileName = sourceUrl.lastPathComponent!
let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryUrl!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

//Hold this file as an NSData and write it to the new location
if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: sourceUrl) {
    fileData.writeToURL(destinationURL, atomically: false)   // true

    let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL:destinationURL)
    viewer.delegate = self
    viewer.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
}
```

I don't want this to be stored permanently however - just to allow users to see the file when they click on the 'open' button.

Is there a way to put the file somewhere like a /temp folder where stuff is deleted automatically, or alternatively, how would I remove the file when the preview is closed?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a temp directory for your app, you can review [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) to find more detail on the directories available to your app. You are expected to manage the life cycle of the files in question.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684252/deleting-files-from-temp-directory-on-ios) for deleting a file from this directory.

The directory your interested in is `tmp/`

Form the documentation:

> Use this directory to write temporary files that do not need to
>   persist between launches of your app. Your app should remove files
>   from this directory when they are no longer needed; however, the
>   system may purge this directory when your app is not running. The
>   contents of this directory are not backed up by iTunes.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more quick question - I can't seem to write to `tmp/` - the code I'm using is `let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryUrl!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("tmp/"+fileName)` - is there something wrong there?

Comment: Print out the url and see if the path is correct. You can also use the devices option  under the window menu option in Xcode and look at the app's directories if your using a device.

Comment: Bingo - thanks! I was using the Documents/tmp directory rather than just /tmp.